# Can the 2016 15-inch MacBook Pro (with Touch Bar) drive 4 external monitors?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, gpu

I'm wondering if the 15-inch MacBook Pro with Touch Bar that was announced on October 27, 2016 can drive 4 external monitors? It says it has 4 Thunderbolt 3 ports, but can the graphics card handle 4 monitors?

[image: MacBook Pro Specs]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The 2016 15" MacBook Pro will support up to four external displays.**

You can have either of the following two options:

- Up to two 5K displays
- Up to four 4K displays

Specifically per the [tech specs of the 2016 MacBook Pro](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/):

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display
>   at millions of colors and:
>
> Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a
>   billion colors Up to four displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at
>   60Hz at over a billion colors Thunderbolt 3 digital video output
>
> Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C VGA, HDMI, and Thunderbolt 2
>   output supported using adapters (sold separately)

The 13" model will support up to 2 external displays either

- One 5K display
- Up to two 4K displays

Comment: Where did you find that information at?

Comment: On the tech spec page (click the link) under "Video Support."  You have to scroll down a bit.